# Determine the selected radio button in Web2py

Tags: web2py

My radio buttons are showing ok and they are selectable, but the problem is i cannot seem to find out how to check which radio button is selected.  In controller i am not sure how to check. I have tried saying "if db.users.selection_type=='Facebook':". This what i have written in model.

```
db.define_table('users',
            Field('selection_type', 'list:string', label=''))

db.users.selection_type.requires = IS_IN_SET((‘Facebook’, ‘Google’))
db.users.selection_type.widget = SQLFORM.widgets.radio.widget
```

Comment: Do you want users to be able to make more than one selection? If not, change the field type to 'string'.

Comment: No only one selection is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using `SQLFORM`, the selected value will be in `request.post_vars.selection_type`.

Comment: I have tried what you just suggested but still i cannot find whats selected. this is what i tried 'checked = request.post_vars.selection_type' It still will not work. I also removed the list:string and made it to be just string as suggested but alas.

Comment: Ok so i have instructed it to return what request.post_vars.selection_type contains and it says None. This means the radio button is being selected on view but it doesn't register it as selected behind the scenes. Do you know if i am supposed to do something to register it behind the scenes

Comment: Ok so i realised that your solution is perfect ...i was just not asking in the right place. thank you thank you